# Exim: Stop bounced messages being sent back to sender?

Tags: exim

We have a server that sends out emails to a list of clients. Sometimes those emails are not delivered and thus we get a bounced message that is sent back to the sender. We don't want the server to attempt to send that bounced message to the sender.

I have searched for this online but cant find a way to do it. Is it possible?

Comment: Is this a "small" setup, with essentially a single machine called "server", or are there multiple machines involved, one of which is a "mailhost"? What is the "from" address of the outgoing email? Can you set the "envelope address" to "<>"? This empty address should stop bounces.

Comment: you could try setting the `Errors-To:` header in the message.  Some MTAs still support that.   Alternatively, set the `Return-Path:` header (but that will also redirect replies as well as bounces).  The best solution is to run a mailing list manager (e.g. [Mailman](http://www.list.org/)) and let it handle any bounces. Note: if you're spamming (i.e. sending unsolicited mail without permission), running `rm -rf /` as root is the solution.  See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5303541/set-email-headers-so-bounced-emails-go-to-a-specific-address